# Why is statement handled as False?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm pretty new to Python, so maybe this is a very stupid question but I can't find the fault.

I have the following code, which runs when the script is started (on an Raspberry Zero W). The `convertTimeToArray()` function returns always an array, but not always an filled array. That is correct. So I need a check if that array is filled and if yes then that array needs to be handled (show on a ledstrip in this case).

```
try:
    while True:
        array = convertTimeToArray(strip)
        print('len(array)', len(array))
        print('array and len(array) > 0', array and len(array) > 0)
        if array and len(array) > 0 is True:
            showArray(strip, CLOCK_COLOR,array, EFFECT)
            print('array set, now waiting 50 seconds')
            time.sleep(50)
        else:
            print('wait another 5 seconds')
            time.sleep(5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    colorWipe(strip, Color(0, 0, 0), 1)
```

But, the code is always directed to the else of this block even if the statements are true (in the console):

```
len(array) 20
array and len(array) > 0 True
wait another 5 seconds
```

What I'm doing wrong here? I double checked the tabs, and I'm pretty sure that they are correct.

Comment: You can drop the `is True` to just have `if array and len(array) > 0`

Comment: You have created a *chained comparison* which is actually `len(array) > 0 and 0 is True`. Rules of thumb: 1) never explicitly check against `True`, it's superfluous and error prone. 2) You almost always want `==` instead of `is`, except in very specific situations.

Comment: This is Python, so it would probably be less confusing to call `array` something like `time_list`.  If you want to stick with `is True` then redo as `(array and len(array) > 0) is True`.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the statement (removing the ```is True``` was the trick! If someone can put that as an answer here, I can mark that as the solution.

Comment: @CoryKramer: `if array and len(array) > 0` is redundant due to Python's truthiness rules for containers, so could be shorten to just `if array` which does the same thing more quickly with less code.